# sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 Error using store procedure

Tags: php, sqlsrv

It is not dublicated question. im trying print records from my db (IIS, MSSQL PHP) but i have this error...

```
<?php
    require_once 'connection.php';
    $uspCall_Actividades="call usp_SelectCountActividades()";
    /*Executando el query*/
    $rsActividad=sqlsrv_query($connection1,$uspCall_Actividades);

    while ($objRs=sqlsrv_fetch_object($rsActividad)){
        echo($objRs->cantidad);
    }

?>
```

**Error:** Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Comment: Can you show your $connection1 variable

Comment: @DannyBroadbent show content variable

$serverName = "IpServer SQL";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbtester", "UID"=>"hdezcths", "PWD"=>"tester);
$connection1 = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

Comment: Please update into your post (also remove sensitive info

Comment: Your server name is also suppose to be serverName\instanceName, if its "IpServer" for server name and "SQL" for instance you should be doing "IpServer\SQL", you also have a double quote missing after your password value.

Comment: @DannyBroadbent That information is test.

Comment: @DannyBroadbent The values of the connection are good, because I'm using the same CONNECTION another page and has no problem, the problem is when I use a store procedure.

Comment: So then have you tried using: "{call usp_SelectCountActividades()}" on $uspCall_Actividades

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$uspCall_Actividades="call usp_SelectCountActividades()";
```

to use {} brackets:

```
$uspCall_Actividades="{call usp_SelectCountActividades()}";
```

You should also always wrap the while in a check

```
if($rsActividad === false) {
     echo "Error in executing statement 3.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} else {
    while (...) {
         ...
    }
}
```

Also specify any parameters you need:

```
$params = array( 
    array($text, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)               
);
$rsActividad=sqlsrv_query($connection1,$uspCall_Actividades,$params);
```